# Can't use app with Firebase on my phone, but I can on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to run my app on my phone (4.4.2) and I get the following errors:

```
02/09 18:48:02: Launching app 
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/luisacabs/Documents/POLIMI/SharemyFlat/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.android.sharemyflat
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.sharemyflat/com.example.android.sharemyflat.Activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 8045 on device enspert-highway-0123456789ABCDEF
V/Provider/Settings: from db cache, name = anr_debugging_mechanism , value = 1
D/asset: AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
D/dalvikvm: open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk@classes.dex
D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.example.android.sharemyflat
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a19c98)
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5052)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5037)
W/System.err:   ... 12 more
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.sharemyflat, PID: 8045
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5052)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.android.sharemyflat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5037)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4623) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Application terminated.
```

I'm using a MacBook Pro and I can run my app in an emulator and none of these errors appear, so I think maybe the problem is my phone configuration. I have USB debugging enabled as well. Do I need to install anything on phone?

This is my app graddle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.bauthentication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try uninstall then reinstalling the app in your device. Could be a problem because the app trying to read previous app data. As in the error log, `com.example.android.sharemyflat-2.apk`, should be without `-2` suffix.

Comment: can you please tell me what API level your phone is or which Android Version is installed at your phone? Can you also please post your gradle build file?

Comment: My phone android version is 4.4.2

Comment: can you please check your debug apk file? Unzip the file and check if you can see a file classes.dex and something like classe-2.dex

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you config or see documentation of firebase..

official page - [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

be careful with the version of firebase, exist a version old and new, check what version  do you  installed

Official Page Old version.  [Android Quickstart - Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)

Comment: I think everything is according the documentation of firebase. It's weird because on an emulator I have no problems using the app

Answer (score 0):

t looks like that this problem is caused by the Multidex compiler. You may need to configure your App properly for Android Phones with a version <21.

please see the following post. It handles the same topic

[Android app working perfect in marshmallow and lollipop or nougat but it does not work in kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297894/android-app-working-perfect-in-marshmallow-and-lollipop-or-nougat-but-it-does-no/42301478#42301478)

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***.****"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled false
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.12"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Uninstall the app and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the multidex compiler using `multiDexEnabled false`, it should work.