# Android app working perfect in marshmallow and lollipop or nougat but it does not work in kitkat

Tags: android, sdk

In my android app, It's worked on marshmallow or higher version but not in kitkat. I already set minSdkVersion 15 targetSdkVersion 25. When I test in kitkat version API 19 App is unfortunately stopped.I got error. I attache error log. Help me. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: does your kitkat phone have the proper google play services installed?

Comment: In the future, post your stack traces as text, not as images.

Comment: ok @CommonsWare

Comment: Yes but actually I used   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0' in grade file If I change version 10.0.0 then it's not working in marshmallow Now, what to do ? @Kushan

Comment: this error looks that it is related to multidex. Can you please check your generated apk file? does it include more the one classes.dex file (classes2.dex, classes3.dex)?

Comment: How to check app file? @MichaelMeyer

Comment: you can unzip the apk file

Comment: yes In my ask there is classes.dex and classes2.dex file now what to do ? @MichaelMeyer

Comment: See my answe below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that this problem is caused by the Multidex compiler. You may need to configure your App properly for Android Phones with a version <21.

You have to create your own application class and register this class at the Manifest xml file